# How often do dropped out weights get updated

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dropout

I am working on a problem with little data. I am augmenting the training set, i.e. I am rotating my images by up to 12 degrees in both directions:

[image: just an example of rotation, not actual train image]

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html

Since I only have my work-PC to work with (only i5 CPU) my batch_size is small. So small in fact that I only process one image, with its rotations, per batch (ofc. only using tiny learning_rate).

What I need to know is, if the dropout gets updated per picture or per batch. Because if it is per batch, I would need to change tactics.

Answer (score 1):

Dropout is updated per batch_size you define in [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), if unspecified the default is 32.

[Dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout)

> The Dropout layer randomly sets input units to 0 with a frequency of rate at each step during training time

[Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs-in-tensorflow)

> A training step is one gradient update. In one step batch_size examples are processed

Comment: in my case, I work with generators, so batch_size is difined by yielding size. But I get your point. Thanks! Bad for me though -> need to change tactic ...

Comment: I think this question is still valid, because the dropout being updated per betch, does not necessarily mean that the same weights are dropped out per train input. No?

Comment: Answering the question does not invalidate it. The weights which are dropped are randomised every step, provided there is more than one training step for the input the weights being dropped will change.

Comment: but is it the same weights that are being dropped in the same batch? Can I have the same picture, slightly augmented, in the same batch, or do they always have to be seperated, because the same batch means same dropped weights?

Comment: In short yes, same batch = same dropped weights. I'd wonder what the problem with that is though, your neural network is not going to develop any reliance on those weights being dropped provided you have many steps and epochs, I'm happy to talk it over with you in discussion if you like.

Comment: I want to apply different dropouts, on the same (similar) input.

Comment: Two options then, 1. batch the similar input separately, which it sounds like you don't want to do. 2. Train over multiple epochs. Epochs are complete passes over the whole input. If you have 50 batches of images, there will be 50 steps in an epoch.  the dropout will be different each step, including on subsequent epochs. Too many Epochs can cause overfit but dropout is a good way to [prevent overfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69814649/validation-accuracy-is-fluctuating/69829043#69829043).